# Как сократить код до одной строки

Tags: python, циклы, оптимизация

цель кода подчитать количество чисел которые больше 9 и кратны 5 ,а конец ввода чисел является ноль

```
a=int(input())
x=0
while a!=0:
    a = int(input())
    if a>9 and a%5==0: 
        x+=1
print(x)
```

Если нельзя сократить его до одной строчки, то хотелось-бы просто узнать как его можно оптимизировать

Comment: Любой код можно сократить до одной строчки. Результат вам не понравится. Зачем вы хотите сократить код? Что вы хотите оптимизировать? Скорость? Используемую память? Что-то ещё?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание задачи. Без неё оптимизировать код не получится.

Answer (score 7):

Можно использовать функцию `iter`:

```
print(sum((x > 9 and x % 5 == 0) for x in map(int, iter(input, "0"))))
```

Answer (score 3):

В первом числе что, длина? Тогда как-то так:

```
print(sum(x>9 and x%5==0 for x in (int(input()) for _ in range(int(input())))))
```

Comment: Во вводе нет счётчика в начале. Вводятся все числа до нуля. Я думаю что автор допустил ошибку пропустив первое число.

Comment: Я дописал условие программы, так яснее?

Answer (score 2):

До одной так до одной :)

```
exec('x=0\nwhile(a:=int(input()))!=0:x+=(a>9 and a%5==0)\nprint(x)')
```

Comment: Браво! :)))))))

Comment: Смешно, респект! :)

Answer (score 1):

До одной не смогу, а оптимизировать - пожалуйста.

```
x = 0
while a := int(input()):
    x = x + 1 if a > 9 and a % 5 == 0 else x
print(x)
```